# Should we ask if old issues are resolved?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of old questions out there. Many of them does not have answers. Should we comment the questions and ask if the peeps have resolved their issues?

E.g. I asked someone [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/shared-calendars-from-office365) if he had resolved is issue.

Answer (score 2):

No harm in posting a comment, I suppose, especially if the topic is of personal interest to you. But I'd be wary about doing it en masse.